# Is recording of other people in a work context without permission legal in Romania?

Tags: criminal-law, privacy, european-union, recording, romania

I am shortly going to Romania to perform an IT Audit.

As an auditor, we often have to deal with people who become hostile towards us. For my own protection, in the United Kingdom I always video record interactions with the police etc.

What are the filming laws in Romania? It's possible that I may have to film the police if they are called, or if staff of shops become confrontational, because I may have to take pictures of equipment within shops to gather evidence of non-compliance.